# Laravel Save value in session or Cookie

Tags: php, laravel

I need to save a value before redirect and re-use it after redirect back to my website,
the flow is:

- Set value in session

```php
    session(['name' => 'value']);
    session()->save();

    return redirect($checkout_session->url);
```

- Controller return an URL
- Client will be redirected to this
- Go back on my website and than I'll check all session values, but it is empty.

```php
    public function checkSession( {
        dd(session()->all());
    }
```

I dont understand why

Comment: by calling dd() in your code your previous session manipulations will be reverted

Answer (score -1):

To save value in session, try:

```
session()->put('key', 'value');
```

Comment: do not work. After redirect to another website, and come back to my website, session are value are lost